# Modify Headers In Selenium test framework

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I'm trying to create an automated test framework using specflow and selenium and I need to pass basic auth, as well as x-forwarded-for header information to the browser for some of the tests. I see solutions for Browser mob proxy but it seems like that project is dead. I tried using Titanium Proxy but I'm having a heck of a time getting it to work. I'm mostly having trouble understanding what I need to do with certificates to get my webdriver to use the proxy and load the sites without fussing. Currently I can't get it to open http or https sites.  When I run my test case I can see that the browser is correctly setting the proxy so I don't think that's the case. I left commented out code for things I tried to do to set a certificate but I'm not 100% sure what I'm actually doing there. Any help would be appreciated. 
Alternatively if there is a better, easier way to add headers to a request I'm all ears.

```
public class ProxyService
{
    private ProxyServer server;

    public int port { get; }

    public ProxyService(int port)
    {
        this.server = new ProxyServer();
        //server.CertificateManager.CreateServerCertificate("rootCert.pfx");
        //server.CertificateManager.LoadRootCertificate();
        //server.CertificateManager.CertificateEngine = Titanium.Web.Proxy.Network.CertificateEngine.BouncyCastle;
        //server.CertificateManager.TrustRootCertificate(true);
        //server.CertificateManager.EnsureRootCertificate(true,true,false);
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void AddHeader(string key, string value)
    {


    }
    private async Task OnRequest(object sender, SessionEventArgs e) => await Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            e.HttpClient.Request.Headers.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxx");

        });

    public void Start()
    {
        var endpoint = new ExplicitProxyEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port, true);
        server.AddEndPoint(endpoint);

        server.Start();
        server.BeforeRequest += OnRequest;
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        server.Stop();
    }
}
```